# emacs next-screen-context-lines ignored

Tags: emacs, scroll

This is probably a very obvious question, but I seem to have missed something. When I first started using emacs about a month ago, pressing C-v would scroll down and leave two line at the top of the screen, à la tutorial. Somewhere along the line I must have upgraded packages, and it now places the cursor at the top of the screen - no context lines.

Running `C-u -2 C-v` works as expected, so I tried `M-x set-variable RET next-screen-context-lines RET 2`, which had absolutely no effect. According to `C-h v RET next-screen-context-lines`, I can set the variable to any positive or negative number I choose, but pressing `C-v` always results in the cursor moving to the top of the screen and now context lines. Incidentally, `M-v` has the same problem. I can't find a relevant setting in my .emacs, but I tried `mv .emacs .emacs.bak` and noticed no difference.

I'm running `GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.22)  of 2013-12-22 on binet, modified by Debian` according to `C-h C-a`

Other than that, emacs is an amazing program I wish I'd used before, and which has now all but replaced libreoffice for me (with the help of RST). Now to learn to touch type...

Many thanks in advance for your time.

**[EDIT]**: I was wrong, the point moves as well and I hadn't noticed (see below). The variables suggested below are useful, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your value of user option `scroll-margin`: `C-h v RET scroll-margin RET`.  The default value is 0.  Try setting it to 2.

There are also other scrolling-related options whose values you can check. Try `M-x apropos-option RET ^scroll RET`.  (Ignore any hits for `scroll-bar`.)

Comment: Thanks - this does give me something like the functionality I was looking for, by setting it from 0 to 2. None of the other variables, however, seem to restore `C-v` to behaving as the tutorial says it should. I'll try on an older version to see if I am making this up. That said, this is a very useful option, and the prevalence of variables is what makes emacs so easy to customise.

Comment: Sorry, I think i've just been being being very stupid. EMACS _does_ have the correct behaviour, I just hadn't noticed it because the pint moves (which of course, is to be expected). I've edited the question, but thanks very much for the reply, as this variable is actually really quite useful. I _knew_ I was being stupid.